# Issues related to SVR in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am working on support vector regression for aerospace applications. I need to implement SVR in MATLAB. On the internet, I found [this link](http://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitrsvm.html?requestedDomain=in.mathworks.com#inputarg_HyperparameterOptimizationOptions), which gives detailed information with examples. When I try running the example codes in matlab, I am getting this error,

```
Error using classreg.learning.FitTemplate/fillIfNeeded (line 604)
OptimizeHyperparameters is not a valid parameter name.

Error in classreg.learning.FitTemplate.make (line 124)
            temp = fillIfNeeded(temp,type);

Error in RegressionSVM.template (line 349)
            temp = classreg.learning.FitTemplate.make('SVM','type','regression',varargin{:});

Error in RegressionSVM.fit (line 343)
            temp = RegressionSVM.template(varargin{:});

Error in fitrsvm (line 235)
obj = RegressionSVM.fit(X,Y,varargin{:});
```

I am using MATLAB R2016a. Kindly let me know, how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today. Just upgrade Matlab to Matlab 2016b and it should work. Maybe it's a new parameter that they just introduced.